# Laravel - Add different style to type of product

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm working on a project where I have products. Each product can either be a theme, plugin or a plan. Now my idea was to add different styles to each of the types. For instance, Theme is red, Plugin is blue etc... Now in my blade file I have handled this in the following way:

```
@if($product->productable_type == "App\Theme")
<td><span class="badge badge-success" style="padding: 4px;">{{ $product->productable_type  }}</span></td>
@elseif($product->productable_type == "App\Plugin")
<td><span class="badge badge-primary" style="padding: 4px;">{{ $product->productable_type  }}</span></td>
@else
<td><span class="badge badge-secondary" style="padding: 4px;">{{ $product->productable_type  }}</span></td>
@endif
```

But is this the best way to handle these kinds of situations? It does not look clean at all. What is the best way to handle this?

The product DB looks like this.:

```
Products
    - id
    - productable_type (Either "App\Theme" or "App\Plugin" etc...)
    - productable_id
    - name
    - description
    - etc...
```

Thanks in advance!